Cannot autoload with TFTPGET | U-Boot
I got Debian working on my Olimex Lime 2 with official images today. I installed Wireguard and attempted to reboot but am getting these errors:
U-Boot 2021.04*olimex-1-20231103.141125 (Nov 03 2023 - 13:12:2* +0000) Allwinner Technology
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A89D237
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A89D23
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
Speed: 100, full duplex
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A89D2
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not et
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A89D
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A89
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A8
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0A
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-sunxi-a20_olinuxino
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-sunxi
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default
Speed: 100, full duplex
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
missing environment variable: bootfile
Config file not found
Speed: 100, full duplex
BOOTP broadcast 1
DHCP client bound to address <ip> (104 ms)
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
Cannot autoload with TFTPGET
Speed: 100, full duplex
BOOTP broadcast 1
DHCP client bound to address <ip> (104 ms)
*** ERROR: 'serverip' not set
Cannot autoload with TFTPGET
=>

(Note: Error message manually typed out)

Any ideas what the issue might be? The device its self is a brand new Olimex Lime 2 (A20-OLINUXINO-LIME2-E16GS16M-ND) from DigiKey.
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
